# What reason could explain why my references in C# same solution not detected?

Tags: c#

I have a solution in which there are several project. Lets call those project A, B, C ...etc

Project A is a WinForm project, while project B is a class library project.

What I tried is to `add a reference` in project A that points to project B : as a result, its class library should be accessible in A.

But when I'm in project A classes, when I try to do `using B`, it does not work (not even showed in intellisense).

Any idea of what would be the reason of this ?

Comment: do you have a public class with public methods or members in B? Is B the namesapce... can you show a minimum example?

Comment: @user1892538  Omg My bad. I forgot to declare classes of B as `public`. When I did that, I was then able to add B namespace in project A classes.

Comment: @MarkC.  I did that. Also, see my above comment. It was my mistake.